# SSRS - Column Chart - Label style

Tags: reporting-services, column-chart

how to show column chart labels on x-axis 1st is down while 2nd is up?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot choose to display your labels in this manner.  This is a result of the automatic formatting that SSRS does to render your chart.  All you can do is to try and set the font size large enough to ensure that there is just too little space in your chart width to display all your labels, in which case the report *may* format your labels like this.